# Looping inside looping with php

Tags: php, foreach

So what I wish to accomplish is:

```
<div class="product-box">
    <ul class="product-list">

    <li><a href="http://sauritchsurfboards.com/longboards.html" title="Surfboards _ San Diego Surfboard Shapers _ Sauritch Surfboards-2" target="_blank"><span>Surfboards _ San...</span>
    </a></li>

    <li><a href="http://sauritchsurfboards.com/longboards.html" title="Surfboards _ San Diego Surfboard Shapers _ Sauritch Surfboards-2" target="_blank"><span>Surfboards _ San...</span></a></li>

    <li><a href="http://sauritchsurfboards.com/longboards.html" title="Surfboards _ San Diego Surfboard Shapers _ Sauritch Surfboards-2" target="_blank"><span>Surfboards _ San...</span></a></li>

    <li><a href="http://sauritchsurfboards.com/longboards.html" title="Surfboards _ San Diego Surfboard Shapers _ Sauritch Surfboards-2" target="_blank"><span>Surfboards _ San...</span></a></li>

    <li><a href="http://sauritchsurfboards.com/longboards.html" title="Surfboards _ San Diego Surfboard Shapers _ Sauritch Surfboards-2" target="_blank"><span>Surfboards _ San...</span></a></li>

    <li><a href="http://sauritchsurfboards.com/longboards.html" title="Surfboards _ San Diego Surfboard Shapers _ Sauritch Surfboards-2" target="_blank"><span>Surfboards _ San...</span></a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I have a `$griditems` which is a array from the database.

I would like to show 6 .product-box'es with 6 `<li>`'s inside  that is from this `$griditems`

Normally I would just have done:

```
<div class="product-box">
    <ul class="product-list">
<?php
$count=1;
foreach($griditems as $item)
{
  if($count == 6) { break; }
?>
<li><a>.....</a></li>
<?php
 $count++;
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

But this will not work in this case, since I would like to have 6 of these .product-box classes, and inside each .product-box should be these 6 items, which should continue from eachother and not repeating the same first 6 that exists in the `$griditems` array.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please correct me if I misunderstood your question, but you're trying to make individual lists of 6 items each, all coming from `$griditems`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_chunk` to split the array into sub-arrays of a certain maximum length.

```
$chunks = array_chunk($griditems, 6);
foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo "<div><ul>";
    foreach($chunk as $item) echo "<li>".$item."</li>";
    echo "</ul></div>";
}
```

Incidentally, it's not great practice to use an HTML element merely to house a single, other HTML element, so your DIV may be superflous.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the mod operator (`%`) to check for every sixth item, and then close the existing box and start a new one, something like this:

```
?>
<li><a>.....</a></li>
<?php
    if ($count % 6 == 0) { ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div  class="product-box">
    <ul class="product-list">
<?php }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question, but I think this will help:

```
$count = 0;
echo "<ul>"
foreach($griditems as $item) {
    if (++$count % 6 == 0) {
        echo "</ul><ul>";
    }
    echo "<li><a>....</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```